# Update table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

We are getting data from excel source and keeping in Temp table and updating target table using temp table with Stored Procedure.I am facing problems with 'comments' column in target table where if a new comment comes in then it should prepend to the existing comment. The riddle here is target table column is a combination of input parameters and some fields along with comments.Eg:

```
[Target.Comments] = '[Manager ' + @Getdateparameter +'' + uploaded by + '] ' +Temp.comments + '' + Target.comments.
```

When a new record comes in today,

```
Comment  =  [Manager1 May_9_2013 uploader1] robert is in canada
```

If you run again in another day and there is no update (it should check with existing comment) in the comment then

```
Comment  =  [Manager1 May_9_2013 uploader1] robert is in canada
```

If there is an update in the comment on May 15 th then it should be

```
Comment = [Manager1 May_15_2013 uploader1] robert is moved away from canada and now he is in US.[Manager1 May_9_2013 uploader1] robert is in canada
```

How to achieve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your don't provide any real info to actually write code for you (are you looping, inserting in a single statement, etc), but try something like this:

```
UPDATE y
    SET YourComment=t.NewValue+ISNULL('; '+y.YourComment,'')
    FROM YourTable                y
        INNER JOIN YourTempTable  t On y.PK=t.PK
    WHERE t.NewValue IS NOT NULL
```

I coded it to place a "; " between comments, but you can remove if not necessary.  Replace "t.NewValue" with your string concatenation that forms the new comment.

**This is really a schema problem.**  You should create a Comments table, where you split out your different values into their own columns, and have one row per comment.  At that point, you always insert and no updates or concatenations.  You can use a view or in application processing to combine them for user presentation.

Comment: i wrote the update statement inside a cursor and the update statement is,           Update target tar set tar.comments= case when temp.comments is not null then '[Manager ' + @Getdateparameter +'' + uploaded by + '] '+temp.comments + '' + tar.comments else tar.comments end from target_atble inner tar join temmp_table temp on tar.PK = temp.PK.                    This works fine until the same comment is coming on different day, then we have duplicate comments in the field.

Comment: please tell me that `uploaded by` isn't a column name? how does that even work with a space in there? can't you add `WHERE YourOldComment NOT LIKE '%'+YourNewComent+'%'`

Comment: And please never write updates or inserts or deletes in a cursor! Very bad habit you need to break. You need to think in sets not processing one record at a time.

Comment: Have to agree strongly that this is a design problem, you should refactor the database to correctly store information in a relational fashion.

Comment: @KM : I can't add the WHERE condotion you specified, because NewComment has to look for the recent comment and not the entire comment.

Comment: @HLGEM: Thanks! I will make changes to my code to not use cursors. I know it's a distgusting field, but I just joined the team and started working on Prod database.